# ng-repeat does not work on Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have created a controller (movies.js) as below-

```
'use strict';
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.movies = [
        {
        title:'Star Wars!',
        url:'http://www.google.com'
        },
        {
        title: 'Star Wars2!',
        url: 'http://www.google.com'
        },
        {
        title: 'Star Wars3!',
        url: 'http://www.google.com'
        }
    ];
  });
```

Now I'm trying to access the values of each objects using ng-repeat in movies.html-

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>URL</th>    
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
<td> {{ movie.title }} </td>
<td> {{ movie.url }} </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

However, the values are not populated as expected. Can someone please provide any tips on where should I look to fix it?

Comment: `$scope.movies` instead of `this.movies`

Comment: Tried that too, but does not work

Comment: Did you specify `ng-controller ` and `ng-app` in your html markup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are assigning the array to `this` so

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  this.movies = [{
    title: 'Star Wars!',
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
  }, {
    title: 'Star Wars2!',
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
  }, {
    title: 'Star Wars3!',
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController as ctrl">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>URL</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="movie in ctrl.movies">
          <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or assign the array to the scope variable

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.movies = [{
    title: 'Star Wars!',
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
  }, {
    title: 'Star Wars2!',
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
  }, {
    title: 'Star Wars3!',
    url: 'http://www.google.com'
  }];
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <table class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>URL</th>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
          <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
          <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject `$scope` into your controller, and use that to bind your array to your view

```
.controller('MoviesCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.movies = [
        {
            title:'Star Wars!',
            url:'http://www.google.com'
        },{
            title: 'Star Wars2!',
            url: 'http://www.google.com'
        },{
            title: 'Star Wars3!',
            url: 'http://www.google.com'
        }
    ];
});
```

Also, don't forget that you need to specify in your view that there is a controller you want to use. For example, in your html:

```
<div ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
    <!-- any html you associate with your controller -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
'use strict';
angular.module('validationApp' ,[])
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.movies = [
        {
        title:'Star Wars!',
        url:'http://www.google.com'
        },
        {
        title: 'Star Wars2!',
        url: 'http://www.google.com'
        },
        {
        title: 'Star Wars3!',
        url: 'http://www.google.com'
        }
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>URL</th>    
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="movie in MoviesCtrl.movies">
<td> {{ movie.title }} </td>
<td> {{ movie.url }} </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

or you should bind it to $scope.movies

Answer (score 0):

Still you won't be able to load external URLs. You need to make a filter to whitelist the external links. Refer below code.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .filter('trustUrl', function ($sce) {
    return function(url) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
  };
});

<td> {{ movie.url | trustUrl}} </td>
```